# twitter scrapy not returning

Tags: python, scrapy

im new to scrapy and just having a few issues collecting my scraped data.
so far i have..

```
import scrapy


class userScrape(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'uscraper'
    allowed_domains = ['twitter.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'
        tag = getattr(self, 'username', None)
        if tag is not None:
            url = url + tag
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = scrapy.Item()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('.//@data-name').extract()[0]
        item['tweet_count'] = response.css('.ProfileNav-value::text').extract()[0]
        return item
```

and...

```
import scrapy


class UserscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    tweet_count = scrapy.Field()

    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

when i scrape using.. "scrapy crawl uscraper -a username=Twitter" i am not returning any of my requested scraped data..

please see my results.

```
(base) C:\Users\NevilleBartos\userscrape>scrapy crawl uscraper -a       
username=Twitter
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot:       
userscrape)
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.1.0.0, libxml2      
2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.1, parsel 1.2.0, w3lib 1.18.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 
3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 17.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017), 
cryptography 2.0.3, Platform Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME':   
'userscrape', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'userscrape.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': 
['userscrape.spiders']}

2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader    
middlewares:

['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']

2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:

['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0    
pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console    
listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-02-27 10:53:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG:   
Redirecting (301) to <GET https://twitter.com/Twitter> from <GET   
https://www.twitter.com/Twitter>

2018-02-27 10:53:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://twitter.com/Twitter> (referer: None)
2018-02-27 10:53:45 [uscraper] DEBUG: callback "parse": got response <200 
https://twitter.com/Twitter>
2018-02-27 10:53:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-02-27 10:53:45 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 530,
'downloader/request_count': 2,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
'downloader/response_bytes': 52800,
'downloader/response_count': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 27, 9, 53, 45, 766083),
'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 27, 9, 53, 44, 811702)}
2018-02-27 10:53:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

when using the scrapy shell i can extract the necessary data e.g. 

scrapy shell https:/twitter.com/Twitter
response.xpath('.//@data-name').extract()[0]
```

my result is 'Twitter' as expected.. so with this i think i have an issue with my callback for my spider or my parse_item. any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code is calling `parse_item()`.
You will have to either call it yourself or make it a callback for a request.

One example of how this might be done:

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)
    return self.parse_item(response)
```

Another option is having your item parsing code directly in `parse()`.